# How can I use SQL function in TableGateway where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, zend-framework2

I am trying to use the SQL `CURDATE()` in Zend-Framework2 TableGateway but I get an exception;

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CURDATE' in 'where clause'

**Here's my code:**

```
$where_clause = "date between CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)";   
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select($where_clause);
```

Is there a better way of creating an SQL statement with a where clause?

Comment: Do you need to use `CURDATE()` in the ADDDATE call, so MySQL knows it's a function call and not a column?

Comment: @andrewsi It was indeed that, now it works; thank you. Can you write it as an answer so that I can select it as the solution?